# NSIS Why does CopyFiles work in one example and not the other?

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I am having difficulty using the `CopyFiles` command and the value I read from the UninstallString registry. The value of the UninstallString is `"C:\myapp\uninstall.exe"` (with quotes).

If I try the following it does not work.

```
CopyFiles $uninstallPath "C:\Temp" # Does not work
```

Next, I edit the registry and remove the quotes from UninstallString's value so it is `C:\myapp\uninstall.exe`.

The following works, but it is not surrounded by quotes.

```
CopyFiles $uninstallPath "C:\Temp" # Works
```

Now I add quotes around the variable and it works.

```
CopyFiles "$uninstallPath" "C:\Temp" # Works
```

I feel like the first and last examples are two different ways of doing the same thing. Any clarity on why the first example does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing apples to oranges, or in your case, quotes vs. stripped quotes.

The outermost quotes on parameters in your .nsi are removed by the compiler so

```
StrCpy $0 "Hello World"
MessageBox mb_ok $0
```

is exactly the same as

```
StrCpy $0 "Hello World"
MessageBox mb_ok "$0"
```

However, if you read a string into a variable on the users machine then no quotes are removed:

```
StrCpy $0 '"Hello World"' ; Pretending that we read "Hello World" (with quotes) from somewhere
MessageBox mb_ok $0
```

There is a thread with a bunch of different solutions on the [NSIS forum](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=319961). Here is my take on that type of function:

```
!define PathUnquoteSpaces '!insertmacro PathUnquoteSpaces '
Function PathUnquoteSpaces
Exch $0
Push $1
StrCpy $1 $0 1
StrCmp $1 '"' 0 ret
StrCpy $1 $0 "" -1
StrCmp $1 '"' 0 ret
StrCpy $0 $0 -1 1
ret:
Pop $1
Exch $0
FunctionEnd
!macro PathUnquoteSpaces var
Push ${var}
Call PathUnquoteSpaces
Pop ${var}
!macroend


Section 
!macro Test path
StrCpy $0 '${Path}'
StrCpy $1 $0
${PathUnquoteSpaces} $0
DetailPrint |$1|->|$0|
!macroend
!insertmacro Test 'c:\foo'
!insertmacro Test 'c:\foo bar'
!insertmacro Test '"c:\foo"'
!insertmacro Test '"c:\foo bar"'
SectionEnd
```

Your code should then look something like this after copying my function into your .nsi:

```
ReadRegStr $uninstallPath HKLM "Sofware\...\YourAppUninstKey" "UninstallString"
${PathUnquoteSpaces} $uninstallPath
CopyFiles $uninstallPath "C:\Temp"
```

Comment: Do you not need to be concerned that you're passing the argument $uninstallPath to CopyFiles that may contain a space, but is not surrounded by quotes?

Further, if the quotes are not needed why is it common practice to surround paths stored in registries and then remove them?

Comment: You don't have to quote variables even if they contain spaces, they are expanded on the end-users machine long after the compiler has parsed whatever parameters you have passed to a function in your script. Any command that can be executed should be quoted when stored in the registry while other paths like icons and other files are usually not quoted. See also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070515-00/?p=26863

Comment: I noticed a minor issue with the code. The first StrCpy should be StrCpy $1 $0 1.